# Simple php form1

Tags: php

I am trying to write a simple php form but the out put is different from the one I wanted it to be. Does any one see what my mistake is thanks and appreciate it.
    **The Assignment** :
    Write a PHP script that checks the message sent from the form and then prints the name of the sender and the message. If the sender name or the message is blank, print ”You didn’t give all required information!” Remove any spaces before or after the user name or message. Remove also any HTML tags to make sure the user can’t alter the guestbook. The used form looks like this:

```
<form action="guestbook.php" method="get"> 
    Sender:  <input TYPE="text" name="name"><br>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send">                   
</form>


Example output


John: Hello!

**my script:**

<?php

$name = $_GET["name"];
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    echo "$name: Hello!";
} else {
    echo "You didn’t give all required information!";
}

?>

YOUR PROGRAM DOES NOT OPERATE CORRECTLY
Your program generated the following output:

You didn’t give all required information!


The following output should have been generated:

John: Hello!

    The white area indicates correct output from your program.
    represents a carriage return
    In the comparison of outputs, the output of your program must be exactly the same as the example output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no input named "submit", only one with a *type* submit, which is what you are looking for. Try using `isset($_GET['name'])` in the if-statement instead, since that's what you're actually using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
    echo $_GET['name'].": Hello!";
}
else
{
    echo "You didn’t give all required information!";
}
?>
```

You should be aware though that directly outputting user-inputted data like this is very unsafe, creating a very big [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, when I try your code the output is different  OUR PROGRAM DOES NOT OPERATE CORRECTLY
Your program generated the following output:

John: Hello!

  
The following output should have been generated:

You didn’t give all required information!

    The white area indicates correct output from your program.
    represents a carriage return
    In the comparison of outputs, the output of your program must be exactly the same as the example output.

Comment: You have additional requirements your original question doesn't specify. It sounds like your requirement is to check _both_ the name _and_ message are set before displaying the message. Try changing the line to say `if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['message'])){`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
```

Should be

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP should look like the following:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
if($name != ''){
echo "$name: Hello!";
}
else
{
echo "You didn’t give all required information!";
}
?>
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

Comment: It should be noted that this would not be compatible with [PHP's strict level](http://lampgurus.com/site/b/2012/02/18/strict-mode-in-php.html) compatible – if the page is loaded without the `name` GET parameter sent it would trigger a warning. Adding an `isset` check for the `$_GET['name']` would prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

In your statement :

> if the sender name or the message is blank, print ”You didn’t give all
>   required information!” Remove any spaces before or after the user name
>   or message. Remove also any HTML tags to make sure the user can’t
>   alter the guestbook.

you should have something like this inside of your if statement:

```
if( isset($_GET['name']) ){ 

  $clean_name = trim(strip_tags($_GET['name']));

  echo $clean_name;

}
```

**trim()** to remove extra whitespaces before and after of the string and **strip_tags()** to remove html tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="guestbook.php" method="get"> 
    Sender:  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">                   
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['send'])) {
    $name = trim(strip_tags($_GET['name']));
    if($name != ''){
        echo "$name: Hello!";
    } else {
        echo "You didn’t give all required information!";
    }
}
?>
```